# How can I get commit.committed_date from commit.committer.date.seconds on bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits

Tags: git, google-bigquery

This question is about the Google Big-Query Github public data.

I'd like to get the `committed_date` on `bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits`.
Although there is only `commit.committer.date.seconds`, I don't know how to translate from `commit.committer.date.seconds` to `committed_date`, like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standrad SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT committer.date.seconds, 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(committer.date.seconds)) AS committed_date
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT 10
```

As you can see you can translate seconds into timestamp using TIMESTAMP_SECONDS() and then into date using DATE()

Same in BigQuery Legacy SQL will look like below

```
#legacySQL
SELECT committer.date.seconds, 
  DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(committer.date.seconds)) AS committed_date
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits]
LIMIT 10
```

Note: It is highly recommended to use Standard SQL with BigQuery - I am presenting version for Legacy SQL only because you referenced table in legacy way - so you might looking for it

Comment: Thank you very much, I could do it. Also I use Standard SQL you recommended.